# Detecting circular pattern in image

Tags: c#, c++, opencv, image-processing, emgucv

I have a image. In this image there are some vertical lines and in these lines there appear some circular/elliptical or convex patterns. I want to detect the position of these circular/elliptical or convex patterns using EmguCV / OpenCV. Can any body of you help me in this regard?

This is the image in which i want to find the circular/elliptical patterns:
[image: Input Image]

waiting for your help.

Comment: can you add another image where you mark (colored) which ob the patterns you want/need to detect and which you needn't? e.g. do you need the tiny ones? do you have to divide the big one in the bottom right to two single ones?

Comment: Hello @Micka Thank you for responding. Actually I don't need the tiny one. I need to detect the circles/elliptical patterns which are present on the lines. the big ones. In the bottom right corner i don't need to divide. If I could detect it as a single one It is also ok for me.

Comment: As asked by @Micka, you'd better provide a colored image with exactly what you want to detect. (You will soon realize that this isn't so easy.)

Comment: in the third line from left, do you see one or two patterns you want to detect?

Comment: hello @Micka Please see the below image in which i created the yellow circles of the area which i wanted to detect. Can you please guide me with this. And sorry for uploading this image late. regards. https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/71584543/image_1_colored.png

Answer (score 2):

You can use Hough transform API for finding circles.

http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/CVonline/LOCAL_COPIES/OWENS/LECT6/node3.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try to

- [find contours](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours) (just the outer - `CV_RETR_EXTERNAL`)
- [fill](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=drawcontours#drawcontours) their interiors (draw using -1 for thickness for filling)
- apply a morphology operation for detecting just the blobs (open should solve it; normally `MORPH_RECT` should do it, but please try more sizes to see which one is the best for your purpose)

Now you have just the wanted regions. If you need a point you may:

- detect contours again (just for the blobs)
- [compute the mean point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11567307/calculate-mean-for-vector-of-points) of each contour

---

- or apply the [moments](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=moments#moments) for finding the center of each region